# Sorted difference between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two columns (buying prince and sale price) and I want to calculate the difference between them. After that I want to order the result so I can see all the profit margins.

**Can I do it with just one SELECT statement?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
  SELECT (sale_price - buy_price) AS profit
    FROM table_name
ORDER BY profit DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

Joe has it, but I think you might be looking for something slightly different for the ordering.

Profit margin is defined as net income / revenue.. so the profit margin of each product would be (sale_price minus buy price) divided by sale_price.

```
SELECT (sale_price - buy_price) AS profit FROM table_name 
ORDER BY ((sale_price - buy_price) / sale_price) DESC
```

Good luck.

Comment: Why not just re-use `profit` in the `ORDER BY` rather than doing `sale_price - buy_price` again? :)

Comment: @Joe True. Didn't think that far ahead :)