# Using MySQL order by

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website where users can look up other users. It is a basic search feature, but I want the users' results to be location based. So maybe they search "David". The basic query for the would be

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
where  fname = 'David' or 
       lname= 'David' 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

The problem is that the distance has to be first calculated between each user and the searcher. How can I do this? Not asking to be shown how to calculate distance or anything, just how to logically solve this problem.

Comment: How are you encoding the location? Do you have the current user's location accessible directly from PHP (e.g. in a variable) or do you have to query for that?

Comment: completing nico ... what does distance store in the db? distance between where and where?

Comment: Its accessible directly from PHP using GEOLITE

Comment: The user's latitude and longitude are stored in the db

Comment: similar ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379423/sorted-difference-between-two-columns, might be a duplicate :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The thing is to calculate the distance directly in your select statement and to order the result based on this calculation.

So if you stored the latitude/longitude in the database, you should be able to do something like that:

```
$lat = {CURRENT_USER_LATITUDE};
$long = {CURRENT_USER_LONGITUDE};
SELECT users.*,
6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($lat - ABS(users.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS($lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( ABS(users.latitude) * pi() / 180 ) * POWER(SIN(($long - users.longitude)*pi()/180 / 2),2))) AS distance
FROM users
ORDER BY distance
```

And you might have a much simpler query if you're using the geo data types in MySQL.

Comment: should the caculation as a function or stored procedure?:

Comment: I do it as it is but I guess you can use either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a calculated field like

```
select
    someColumn,
    abs(someValue-someValue2)
from 
    myTable
```

And you need to order by the minimum `abs()` value you need to add it to the order by clause as follows:

```
select
    someColumn,
    abs(someValue-someValue2)
from 
    myTable
order by
    abs(someValue-someValue2) asc
```

Or you can use this syntax:

```
select
    someColumn,
    abs(someValue-someValue2)
from 
    myTable
order by
    2 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT users.*, <distance calculation> AS distance
FROM users
WHERE fname = 'David' or
      lname = 'David'
ORDER BY distance ASC
```